# Oracle can we inverse the POWER function

Tags: sql, oracle, function, math, plsql

Apologies if this has been posted earlier, I have looked but haven't found anything. I don't know the mathematical term for what I'm trying to do so that may be why I haven't found it.

I have a desired result of 75%, I have a table with for e.g. 1500 rows, I need to know what value I have to set those rows to so that the product or power of all those rows = 75.

Through trial and error I know that `POWER(0.99981,1500) = 0.75199`.

Is there a function where I can input 75, 1500 and get 0.99981 as the output?

I have tried LOG but doesn't seem to work or I'm using it wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The direct mathematical definition would be to divide the two natural logs:

```
SELECT POWER(0.99981,1500),
       LN(.751993891229747972713262500887354361902) / LN(0.99981)
FROM DUAL
```

You can also do this with `LOG()`.  The base is the first argument:

```
  log(0.99981, .751993891229747972713262500887354361902)
```

EDIT:

Ooops, to get the base, you can use:

```
exp(ln(.751993891229747972713262500887354361902) / 1500)
```

Comment: Thank you but I won't know the 0.9981. I will only know I want 75 and I have 1500 values to split that across

Answer (score 3):

Mathematically speaking, the nth root of a number is also the number to the power of 1/n, e.g. `sqrt(x) = power(x, 1/2)`

so what you're after is:

```
SELECT POWER(POWER(0.99981,1500), 1/1500) res
FROM   dual;

RES
-------
0.99981
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the mathematical equation:

x<sup>1500</sup> = 0.75

Taking natural logarithms of either side gives:

1500 ln(x) = ln(0.75)

Which can be rearranged to:

ln(x) = ln(0.75)/1500

Taking an exponential function of both sides gives:

e<sup>ln(x)</sup> = x = e<sup>ln(0.75)/1500</sup>

You can convert this from a mathematical equation to Oracle's SQL as:

```
SELECT EXP( LN( 0.75 ) / 1500 ) FROM DUAL;
```

Which outputs:

```
|                        EXP(LN(0.75)/1500) |
| ----------------------------------------: |
| .9998082303418508590582823402912385708058 |
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0c08fa5e325e5e4cc1556867e9814099)*